# Ordered pair in ordered pair

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Easy question, I guess. I probably need clearing of a massive gap in my thinking.

But regarding Cartesian products
$$ A \times B = \{(a,b)\ | \ a \in A \land b \in B\} = S$$

So
$$C \times (A \times B) = C \times S = \{(c,s)\ | \ c \in C \land s \in S\}$$

Since $S$ is a set containing ordered pairs then we will have
$$(c, (a,b)) \in C \times S$$

But the Cartesian product of $C \times (A \times B)$ in numerical examples I've done never have ordered pairs in ordered pairs, just say $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

So my primary concern is whether or not $(c, (a,b)) = (c, a, b)$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed,  $C \times (A\times B)$ is different from $C \times A\times B$, but they can be canonicaly be identified with each other.

So $(c,(a,b))$ is formally different from $(c,a,b)$, but these two objects can also be identified in a not so abusive way

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your definition of ordered triplets. In the book *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* by Elliott Mendelson, page 162, the ordered triple $(c,a,b)$ is *defined* to be $((c,a),b)$. With a slight change, this would be as you wrote, $(c,(a,b))$.

This definition was used to give a completely rigorous definition for $n$-tuples, based on the axioms of set theory. Of course, this follows a rigorous definition of an ordered pair.

Comment: I must add that it's not the only way to define n-tuples (I know you don't imply it, it's just to expand your answer). Another way is to see them as functions $f : \{1,\cdots,n\} \to \bigcup A_i$ with the property $\forall i, f(i) \in A_i$.

Comment: @Tryss: You are correct, of course. Mendelson does not do it your way because he does not define the natural numbers (as finite ordinal numbers) until much later in his book.